# Remove Item from ListBox other than i

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

So basically I have two comboboxes. 1 filter the data so show lists with specific value in the cell. the second combobox basically removes the data from the list in the listbox. however what i want is to remove values other than the ones shown in the listbox. So if i select XYZ i want my code to remove all rows in the listbox that DONT have XYZ in them rather than deleting the ones with XYZ. Please see my code below and let me know if you think of any other changes i should make too. thank you.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

   On Error Resume Next
   For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount
       If ComboBox2.Value = ListBox1.List(i, 6) Then
          ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
       End If
   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. It is always a good idea to go reverse in the loop when removing items, because indexes can change. 2. You have to test for differences, not equality (use <> instead of =).

Comment: It is a very bad practice to use `On Error Resume Next` like this. It hides **all** error messages but the errors will still occur (you just cannot see their messages). That means you cannot fix the errors, and your code might not run correctly + you even don't notice it because there is no message at all. **Remove that line and if you get errors fix them!** • Never use that line without a full and good error handling (see [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)).

Comment: thank you so much for sharing the link. I'm new to coding like a month new so all info is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listbox1` is filled like this:

```
Sub FillListBox()
    Dim data() As Variant
    data = Array("AAA", "CCC", "CCC", "Vityata", "was", "here")
    ListBox1.List = data
End Sub
```

And looks like this:

[image]

The task is to remove all items different than "CCC", without getting an error. Removing from list in VBA is better done upside down. Otherwise the count of the list would cause an error, as far as the list is smaller than it was before removing the item:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Debug.Print ListBox1.List(i)
        If ListBox1.List(i) <> "CCC" Then
            Debug.Print "Removing "; ListBox1.List(i); " from "; i
            ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Last but not least, if you need `On Error Resume Next` in the code to make it work, most probably something will go bad and it will stay unnoticed. Try to avoid it.

Comment: Hello Vityata, thank you so much for such a detailed answer and noted to avoid using on error resume next command. That being said i've shared my entire code and as you can see now what im actually truing to achieve is upon selection of combobox2 value i want everything to be removed from the listbox1 that does not have the value stated in the combobox2 rather than removing the lines with the value selected int he combobox2. So if we talk about your answer, the task would to be remove everything else but "CCC".

Comment: Oh wait changing = to <> worked !!!!
it raises another issue but got this figured out atleast. thank you so much vityata.

Comment: @rjjunior - You are welcome. :) I have rolled back your question to the previous state, as far as it was more consice.